# How to make a cookie convert to a number instead of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, save, local-storage

I'm creating a cookie clicker website and whenever someone clicks the "save" button, I want their score to be saved on localstorage. so far, my code is:

```
let score = 0;

function addpoint() {
  score += 1;
}

 if (localStorage.getItem("score") !== null) {
    score = localStorage.getItem("score");
}
 function savegame() {
   localStorage.setItem("score", score);
   alert("Score has been saved successfully!")
 }
}
```

This sort of works, but if the score variable changes, the code tries to add 1 to a string because the score was saved a string. For example, If I had five points and I saved my game, If I got another point I would have 51 points. Please help soon! I'm not sure if you need to use cookies instead. Thanks!

Comment: Both cookie and localStorage store values as strings. It's up to you to convert those strings to manipulate them depending on type .... array, number, object, boolean etc. In your case convert to number before doing any math. Researching how to convert string to number is a very easy web search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local storage stores values as strings. In your case, you can convert string to number like:

```js
if (localStorage.getItem("score") !== null) {
    score = Number(localStorage.getItem("score"));
}
```

Comment: thanks Deepak! Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

You could try `score = parseInt(score) + 1`. This way when incrementing the score, it is always parsed as an integer.

[MDN - `ParseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)